# Spark Streaming job failing with ArrayBuffer(kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My spark streaming job (spark 1.6.1, kafka 0.9.0) is consuming from Kafka Topic with 20 partitions. 
Offsets are being maintained in oracle DB.

At the the job startup i would read offsets from Oracle(read once), and write offsets to oracle after processing.

My job successfully ran for 8 hrs and then failed with the below reason. There are no changes to kafka topic, spark program, oracle code during the failure.

Can anyone tell why i am getting this error on a running spark streaming job?

```
16/11/02 08:09:21 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1478074160000 ms
org.apache.spark.SparkException: ArrayBuffer(kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException, org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([MyTopic,11]))
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestLeaderOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:246)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: ArrayBuffer(kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException, org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([MyTopic,11]))
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestLeaderOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:352)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:246)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO RecurringTimer: Stopped timer for JobGenerator after time 1478074160000
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO JobGenerator: Stopped JobGenerator
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO JobScheduler: Stopped JobScheduler
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO StreamingContext: StreamingContext stopped successfully
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.251.228.103:4040
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /app/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/local/spark-30fb329c-3ccf-4d8c-a06c-2d36e6f968b3/httpd-f81472a2-3262-4eea-8d64-7ff96d2ef3e5
16/11/02 08:09:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /app/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/local/spark-30fb329c-3ccf-4d8c-a06c-2d36e6f968b3
```

Comment: Try looking at logs in Kafka/ZooKeeper. Check that everything is fine there, up and running and that the disks aren't full.

Comment: @AKC, have you find the answer, why u were facing the issue, as I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was simply that my Kafka server had been interrupted. Easy enough to start it back up:

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server.properties
```

Comment: Especially if you are storing topic/offset information externally, it seems that **Set([MyTopic,11]))** comes from your oracle db, but Kafka is not available to find the matching topic and offset.